# Tail recursion to get data from paginated get API

Tags: scala, recursion, pagination, tail-recursion

Some APIs offers paginated data.
I want to call the API and retrieve the data of all pages.
I was thinking an implementation of it using recursion.
I will call it to retrieve the first page data and the url of next page. If `next page` is empty it means there's no more data to retrieve.

I have this code, which is not really calling an API but it is useful to implement the recursive function I need. The issue I'm facing is that I can't add the `tailrec` annotation, I can't transform it to be tail recursive.

How can I achieve it?

Code for simulating the API which return results in pages:

```scala
final case class Response(data: List[Int], nextUrl: Option[String])

object Api {
  def getNumbers(url: String): Future[Response] = {
    url match {
      case "1" => Future.successful(Response(List(1, 2), Option("2")))
      case "2" => Future.successful(Response(List(3, 4), Option("3")))
      case "3" => Future.successful(Response(List(5, 6), None))
      case _   => Future.failed(new RuntimeException("Error!"))
    }
  }
}
```

Function/method to call the API, which I want to convert it to tail recursion:

```
  def getPaginatedData(url: String): Future[Seq[Int]] = {

    //    @tailrec
    def loop(url: String, acc: Seq[Int]): Future[Seq[Int]] = {
      Api.getNumbers(url).flatMap { response =>
        response.nextUrl match {
          case None       => Future.successful(acc ++ response.data)
          case Some(link) => loop(link, acc ++ response.data)
        }
      }
    }

    loop(url, List.empty)
  }
```

To run the example:

```scala
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    SomeService.getPaginatedData("1").onComplete {
      case Failure(e)     => println(s"Error! $e")
      case Success(value) => println(value)
    }
  }
```

Comment: There is no need to make it tail-recursive since `Future.flatMap` is already stack safe

Comment: As a side-note, appending newly fetched page to the accumulator risks being slow (the whole accumulation becomes quadric in complexity and may put an unnecessary strain on GC if the pages are many and contain many entries each). Collecting a `Seq[Seq[T]]` and then `flatten`ing it once in the end may be preferable.

Comment: Thank you @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, I've coded getPaginatedData from scratch, no tail recursion needed and more cleaner.

Comment: Thank you @DenisAldoshin I'm aware of that.